# How do I create a ContentType for application/schema+json with akka http?

Tags: akka-http

In akka-http there is

```scala
//ContentType.scala
  val `application/json` = ContentType(MediaTypes.`application/json`)
```

In the same vein, how do I create a ContentType for

- `application/schema+json`
- `application/schema-instance+json`

?

Reference:

- https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-core.html
- https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/v10.2.3/akka-http-core/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/model/ContentType.scala#L119
- https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/v10.2.3/akka-http-core/src/main/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/model/MediaType.scala#L357-L358

```scala
//MediaType.scala
  val `application/json`            = awfc("json", HttpCharsets.`UTF-8`, "json")
  val `application/json-patch+json` = awfc("json-patch+json", HttpCharsets.`UTF-8`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Per https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/http-model.html#registering-custom-media-types

Maybe something like:

```scala
object SchemaContentTypes {
  val `application/schema+json`          = ContentType(SchemaMediaTypes.`application/schema+json`)
  val `application/schema-instance+json` = ContentType(SchemaMediaTypes.`application/schema-instance+json`)
}

object SchemaMediaTypes {
  val `application/schema+json`          =
    MediaType.customWithFixedCharset("application", "schema+json", HttpCharsets.`UTF-8`, "schema.json")
  val `application/schema-instance+json` =
    MediaType.customWithFixedCharset("application", "schema-instance+json", HttpCharsets.`UTF-8`)
}
```